# copy_if with map whose value is also a std::pair

Tags: c++, stl, std-pair

I have an input map `inMap` whose type is `map<double, pair<int, double>>`.

I am trying to filter this map by means of `copy_if` like this:

```
map<double, pair<int, double>> outMap;
copy_if(inMap.begin(), inMap.end(), outMap.begin(), [](pair<double, pair<int, double>> item) {return (true) ;} // I have simplified the predicate
```

However, when compiling, I get the following error:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::pair<const double, std::pair<int, double>>& std::pair<const double, std::pair<int, double>>::operator=(const std::pair<const double, std::pair<int, double>>&)
```

Comment: Have you notice the `const` inside the pair (for the key part)?

Comment: You cannot mutate a const object... `std::inserter(outMap, outMap.end())` might help. (Not sure what you want)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iterators of a `std::map` are not suitable for use with `copy_if`, as that algorithm is simply going to attempt to assign the entire value.  However, the iterator of a `std::map` has a value type of `std::pair<const K, V>`, which means it is not copy assignable.

However, you can use [std::inserter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) to accomplish what you want

`std::copy_if(inMap.begin(), inMap.end(), std::inserter(outMap, outMap.end()), Predicate);`